# How to disallow clients of a router to connect each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, wireless-router, routing

Having a regular wireless/router (ADSL router), Can I prevent clients to connect eachother?

My server has ip 192.168.1.2, Wireless router has 192.168.1.1, And clients will have 192.168.1.3~255

How can I prevent these clients connect to each other? Just 192.168.1.2 is allowed for them. I have no control over client machine, I don't know who/what they will be.

I'm sure answer is somewhre but I can't find it.

Comment: What do you not want them able to do? If the response is everything, then they should not be on the same network...

Comment: short answer is no, unless you have full control over the router. what model is your router? can you telnet into it? can you change iptables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computers are on the same local area network then they do not need to router to talk to each other. Thus:

- If the router is acting as a wired switch then you can not prevent it.
- If the client as using an ad-hoc wireless network then you can not prevent it.

However if the computers are wired to the router, and you have full control over it (specifically, being able to configure the firewall of set up VLANs) then you can prevent it.

Still, as AthomSfere already said. If they do not need to connect to each other ever, then why are they on the same network? That is akin to putting lots of people in a room, all talking, and saying they are not allowed to speak to anyone else in the room bar the server. The obvious solution to that is to give each of them their own room.

Comment: That makes sense! I wanted to make sure if someone broke into wireless network, Stop him at pfSense server, Anyone on the network is allowed to connect to some other clients only through pfSense. And there is only two clients with static IP, I want to only allow them to connect.